# NodeJs Express Error Handler to json

Tags: node.js, express, bigcommerce

BigCommerce API sends this error and I want to send the `title` portion only to the client. but the error is a string that is hard to break a part.

I would I likely like to get the same error in Json format so i can get the different parts for different purposes.

> { Error: Request returned error code: 422 and body: {"status":422,"title":"We don't have enough [Sample] Smith Journal 13 stock on hand for the quantity you selected. Please try again.","type":"https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api#api-status-codes"}

```
at IncomingMessage.res.on 
(/Users/ohabash/Dropbox/Sites/fornida_server/node_modules/node-bigcommerce/lib/request.js:83:27)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:164:20)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1054:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9) code: 422 }
```

---

-Do I need to send the request a different way (maybe different headers)?

-Or should parse the response differently? how?**

Comment: https://exceptionshub.com/cant-access-values-in-my-express-nodejs-response-error-string-error-request-returned-error-code-404.html <== same problem

Comment: Have you tried using JSON.parse() on the error response?